# MS SQL: update only the last record of each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table in MS SQL Server that has some unique and duplicate records.

Let's say my table is like

```
Name   Modified    Visibility   UserTypeEx
x      24.05.2015      1           4096
y      01.01.2014      0           4096
z      01.04.2016      1           4096
x      05.03.2015      1           4096
y      06.08.2015      1           4097
y      05.07.2014      1           4096
```

As you can see, I have duplication in the `name` column.  What I am trying to do is to update all `visibility` fields to `0` where the `UserTypeEx` is `4096`, except that where there are duplicate `name`s I want to update only the last-added record among those in each group sharing a `name`.

Such an update would transform the example data to this:

```
Name   Modified    Visibility   UserTypeEx
x      24.05.2015      0           4096
y      01.01.2014      0           4096
z      01.04.2016      0           4096
x      05.03.2015      1           4096
t      06.08.2015      1           4097
y      05.07.2014      0           4096
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use window functions with update.  This is highly convenient:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by modified desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt
      from t
      where UserTypeEx
     )
update toupdate
    set visibility = 0
    where cnt > 1 and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works like a charm